# Serving multiple ad widgets on a single publisher page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ads

My main problem is due to scripts running before DOM is loaded and i can't use `document.ready` event. For more details read further

I am making a ad serving app. I have made a small code snippet which will be given to the publisher to add on their website to load our ads. A specimen of the same is as follows:

```
<div class="my-widget" data-widgetId="1" data-page-url="http://foo.bar/" ></div>
<script src="http://myadserver.exp/js/widget.js"></script>
```

The HTML div is where ads are to be displayed by the script just below it.
This script also contains methods to verify add and fill ads in that div.

```
var adDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('my-widget')[0];
insertScriptWithSouce('http://myadserver.exp/serve.php?id=' + adDiv.dataset.widgetId);

function fillAds(htmlFromserver) {
    adDiv.innerHTML = htmlFromServer;
}
```

> This is only a example to understand the scenario

**Now my problem is if a publisher adds more than one widget on the same page**

That code would look like

```
<div class="my-widget" data-widgetId="1" data-page-url="http://foo.bar/" ></div>
<script src="http://myadserver.exp/js/widget.js"></script>

<div class="my-widget" data-widgetId="2" data-page-url="http://foo.bar/" ></div>
<script src="http://myadserver.exp/js/widget.js"></script>
```

without any of his own html

Now the ad from the second widget get placed in the div of first widget and the second widget remains empty
**I have also tried loops for many classes but when each script runs it does not know that there is another widget below it as it is not yet loaded in the DOM**

> Note: I can not use ids and jQuery as its forbidden by seniors
>   I also cant use `document.ready` event as if document fails to load then my ads will not be served

Comment: Why don't you have them add a code block like Google's one for analytics. Have the code block add any needed elements to the DOM with a unique generated ID (or just ensuring the script only binds to the DOM it adds).

Comment: If an HTML document fails to load you have bigger problems than your ads not displaying. That would be a browser bug. The document will always be parsed at some point.

Comment: @user2867288 If I will use `document.ready` I have to wait for all slow and deadly servers used on the page to load first to serve my ads even when I have a very fast server

Comment: @Cymen The different widgets have different settings to show different ads which can be used on more than one page so its nearly impossible for me to do something like google analytics or if i am wrong please enlighten me in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got nothing as a solution but still got the best way around so I thought it might help someone else

This javascript can be used for solution

```
var adDiv = document.querySelectorAll('my-widget:not([id])');
adDiv = adDiv[0];
adDiv.id = 'my-id' + (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(0);
insertScriptWithSouce('http://myadserver.exp/serve.php?id=' + adDiv.dataset.widgetId + '&origId=' + adDiv.id);

function fillAds(htmlFromserver, idSentFromHere) {
    adDiv = document.getElementById(idSentFromHere);
    adDiv.innerHTML = htmlFromServer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having multiple script blocks, just have one script reference that loops through the ad container divs on the page.

```
function fillAd(htmlFromServer, widgetId) {
    var adDivQuery = document.querySelectorAll('[data-widgetId="' + widgetId + '"]');
    if (adDivQuery.length > 0) {
        adDivQuery[0].innerHTML = htmlFromServer;
    }
}

var adDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('my-widget');

for (var i=0, il=adDivs.length; i<il; i++) {
    insertScriptWithSource('http://myadserver.exp/serve.php?id=' + adDivs[i].dataset.widgetId);
}
```

In this scenario the script inserted by the `insertScriptWithSource()` function will pass a second argument into your `fillAd()` function with the widget ID that was initially passed to it.

Comment: nice try there but i have already done that
the scripts are attached with the widget snippet generated for the publisher which is necessary for each and every snippet as we dont know if the publisher wants to use only one widget or many of them on the same page
so thanks but your answer is of no use to me

Comment: If your publisher only wants to use one widget, they'd place one `<div class="my-widget">` on the page. If they want multiple, place more. Let the dom structure define what widgets get placed on the page.

Comment: you are a developer im a developer but publishers are not they only know copy and pasting if I will not provide the full snippet then they might not be able to include it correctly

Comment: I don't see how asking a publisher to include less tags on the page is making it more difficult for them. Have you actually proposed the solution or is this speculation?

Comment: you are just not getting my point. You understand that `<div class="my-widget" data-widgetId="1" data-page-url="http://foo.bar/" ></div>
<script src="http://myadserver.exp/js/widget.js"></script>` is required for a single widget to work which must be provided by us for pasting. Now just imagine publisher pasting it again and again to make more profit as he knows that pasting this code loads ads. So at I am not giving the multiple widget snippet but a single widget snippet individually which is used by publisher many times

Comment: The way you have it currently setup, yes. There are billions of ways of doing this. Anyhow, it would probably be easier for you to just use iframes and check the HTTP referer from the request header to your site.

Comment: thanx for your support but i cant do that i think i will try to work it around using some flag on the html element still searching for a better approach